# GDB breakpoints confused after a function call?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

I have a program that depends on an external shared library, but after a function inside the library gets executed I lose the ability to use breakpoints.

I can break and step like normal up until I execute this function, but afterwards it is finished it never breaks.  It won't even break on main if I try and use `start` for the second time executing the program.  It's not an inlined function problem, because I've broken on these functions before and when I comment out this particular function everything starts to work again.

Has anyone ever encountered anything like this before?  What can I do?

Using gdb 7.1 with gcc 3.2.3

Edit:
After some hints from users I figured out that the process is forking inside the library call.  I'm not sure what it's doing (and I really don't care).  Can I somehow compensate for this?  I've been experimenting with the follow-fork-mode as child, but I'm really confused what happens once it forks and I can't seem to figure out how to continue execution or do anything of use.

Edit:
Further investigation.  The nearest I can tell, gdb is losing all its symbol information somewhere.  After the 2nd run, all symbols resolve to the @plt address and not to the actual address that they resolved to on the first run.  Like somehow the second loading of the process loses all the info it gained the first time around and refuses to reload it.  I'm so confused!!

Edit:
So I traced down the problem to the vfork of a popen call.  Apparently gdb doesn't play nice with popen?  As soon as I detach from the popen'd vforked process, I lose all my symbols.  I've read some reports online about this as well.  **Is there any hope**?

Comment: Is your shared library spawning a new process?

Comment: Maybe your library call somwhow ends up exiting your calling application?

Comment: gcc 3.2.3 is pretty old, what's the platform? Linux?

Comment: The platform is linux (A redhat EL3 box).  vfork *is* called somewhere inside the library routine.  When I set the follow-mode inside gdb to child, it behaves differently.

Comment: @jdizzle: then that's what's happening.  Mystery solved; your breakpoints apply to the current process and aren't magically inherited by children.

Comment: but the child process isn't continuing executing.  The main process is.  They're just popen system calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I debug the child process after fork() in gdb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199270/how-do-i-debug-the-child-process-after-fork-in-gdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the combination of `vfork(2)` and `exec(2)` that's messing things up. Quoting from `gdb` manual ([debugging forks](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html)):

> On some systems, when a child process is spawned by `vfork`, you cannot debug the child or parent until an `exec` call completes.
> ...
>
> By default, after an `exec` call executes, gdb discards the symbols of the previous executable image. You can change this behaviour with the set `follow-exec-mode` command.

Keep `follow-fork-mode` set to `parent` and set `follow-exec-mode` to `same`.

Alternatively, if your installation supports multi-process debugging (it should, since your `gdb` version is 7.1), try using `info inferiors` to find your original process and switching to it with `inferior <num>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question!  I checked my gdb configuration and follow-fork-mode and follow-exec-mode are already set the way you suggested be default :/.  If I switch the config to follow the child, it breaks after the fork or exec or something, but if I try to switch back to debugging the parent (with inferior <parent-num>) it has no execution context.  It doesn't even think it's being run!

Comment: "On some systems, gdb provides support for debugging programs that create additional processes using the fork or vfork  functions. Currently, the only platforms with this feature are HP-UX (11.x and later only?) and gnu/Linux (kernel version 2.5.60 and later)."  I'm using gdb 7.1, but a 2.4 kernel version :/  Maybe that's also contributing to my problems?

Comment: So I traced down the problem to the vfork of a popen call.  Apparently gdb doesn't play nice with popen?  As soon as I detach from the popen'd vforked process, I lose all my symbols.

Comment: Hmm, 2.4 kernels are pretty much obsolete by now. Any chance of upgrading to 2.6 series? Also try `file` command to load the symbols again.