# How do I debug the child process after fork() in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb, fork

After calling `fork`, the current process will call `exit(0)`.

But the child will continue.

```
switch(fork())
{
  case -1:
    exit(1);
  case 0:
    // child process continues
    break;
  default:
    // the current process exits
    exit(0);
}
```

How can I continue debugging the child process in this case?

Comment: For `exec`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377195/how-to-debug-the-entry-point-of-fork-exec-process/43099366#43099366

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Look at [this](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html). Use:

```
set follow-fork-mode <mode>
```

Set the debugger response to a program call of fork or vfork. A call to fork or vfork creates a new process. The `<mode>` argument can be:

`parent`: The original process is debugged after a fork. The child process runs unimpeded. This is the default.

`child`: The new process is debugged after a fork. The parent process runs unimpeded.

Comment: Is there a way debug both parent and child?

Comment: No, `gdb` does not support simultaneous debugging of multiple processes. But you can use `set detach-on-fork off` to block the parent until the child exits. If your processes do not need to run at the same time, this will do it.

Comment: `gdb` **does** support debugging multiple processes at once. Refer to https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Inferiors-Connections-and-Programs.html , https://stackoverflow.com/q/59735807/5267751 and https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/All_002dStop-Mode.html -- in particular, you can `set follow-fork-mode parent` + `set detach-on-fork off` + `set schedule-multiple on`, then `continue` will run all inferior at once. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/27140941/5267751 to avoid gdb stopping when each inferior stop, or you can use `inferior 1` → `continue`.