# How can I switch between different processes fork() ed in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb, fork

I'm debugging such a multiple process application,

how can I switch between the `fork()`ed processes?

Comment: Incidentally, this appears to be an exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199270/how-do-i-debug-the-child-process-after-fork-in-gdb).

Comment: @Chris,it's different.I want to switch back and force between different processes.

Answer (score 21):

1. You can put the child process to sleep and then attach a new instance of GDB to it. The [GDB User Manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html#Forks) describes this process as follows (emphasis is mine):

   > On most systems, gdb has no special
   >   support for debugging programs which
   >   create additional processes using the
   >   fork function. When a program forks,
   >   gdb will continue to debug the parent
   >   process and the child process will run
   >   unimpeded. If you have set a
   >   breakpoint in any code which the child
   >   then executes, the child will get a
   >   SIGTRAP signal which (unless it
   >   catches the signal) will cause it to
   >   terminate.
   >
   > However, if you want to debug the
   >   child process there is a workaround
   >   which isn't too painful. Put a call to
   >   sleep in the code which the child
   >   process executes after the fork. **It
   >   may be useful to sleep only if a
   >   certain environment variable is set,
   >   or a certain file exists, so that the
   >   delay need not occur when you don't
   >   want to run gdb on the child.** While
   >   the child is sleeping, use the ps
   >   program to get its process ID. Then
   >   tell gdb (**a new invocation of gdb if
   >   you are also debugging the parent
   >   process**) to attach to the child
   >   process (see Attach). From that point
   >   on you can debug the child process
   >   just like any other process which you
   >   attached to.

   The long and the short of it is that when you start a program that later forks, GDB will stay connected to the parent process (though you can follow the child process, instead, by using `set follow-fork-mode child`). By putting the other process to sleep, you can have a new instance of GDB connect to it, as well.
2. Use `set detach-on-fork off` to hold both processes under the control of gdb. By default, the parent process will be debugged as usual and the child will be held suspended, but by calling `set follow-fork-mode child` you can change this behavior (so that the child process will be debugged as usual and the parent will be held suspended). The [GDB User Manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html#Forks) describes this process as follows:

   > gdb will retain control of all forked
   >   processes (including nested forks).
   >   You can list the forked processes
   >   under the control of gdb by using the
   >   `info inferiors` command, and switch
   >   from one fork to another by using the
   >   `inferior` command (see [Debugging
   >   Multiple Inferiors and Programs](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-and-Programs.html#Inferiors-and-Programs)).
   >
   > To quit debugging one of the forked
   >   processes, you can either detach from
   >   it by using the `detach inferiors`
   >   command (allowing it to run
   >   independently), or kill it using the
   >   `kill inferiors` command. See [Debugging
   >   Multiple Inferiors and Programs](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-and-Programs.html#Inferiors-and-Programs).

Comment: so this is not available directly out of the box of gdb?

Comment: @wireshark It should be. You just need to run two instances of GDB: one is attached to the original program and one is attached to the child. You "switch back and forth between different processes" by switching between the two instances of GDB (I've highlighted this in my answer).

Comment: You can also attach and detach from processes from within the same GDB session. `pause`/`sigsuspend` is a better choice than `sleep` if you know you want to connect with GDB, though. The process will then wait till you signal it to continue, and you won't have to race to grab the PID and attach before the process continues the way you would if you relied on `sleep` instead.

Comment: @Jeremy W. Sherman ,it's not working for this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301130/sigint-not-trapped-while-debugging-nginx-with-gdb

Answer (score 3):

Show all the processes.

```
(gdb) info inferiors 
  Num  Description       Executable        
  1    process 1000      /tmp/a.out 
* 2    <null>            /tmp/a.out  # current attach inferior
```

Switch between different processes.

```
(gdb) inferior 1
[Switching to inferior 1 [process 1000] (/tmp/a.out)]
[Switching to thread 1.1 (LWP 1000)]
```