# GDB MI : follow parent process for debugging

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

While using GDB MI instruction I found that in case a program forks to create child process it starts debugging the last child only. So if I try to debug break in parent it does not breaks at that point:

I found this valuable reference in stackoverflow.com:

[How do I debug the child process after fork() in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199270/how-do-i-debug-the-child-process-after-fork-in-gdb)

My question is that how I can set the follow-fork-mode mode and via which GBD MI API?

http://src.gnu-darwin.org/ports/editors/setedit/work/setedit/libmigdb/doc/reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like 123-gdb-set follow-fork parent.

But you can also look into something like:
gdb-set detach-on-fork off