# Using `gdb` with dynamically allocated child processes?

Tags: c, gdb, child-process

I am definitely new to C and `gdb`, but not programming.
I want to debug library referenced by a failing unit-test. There is a child process forked per each unit test (I assume to keep memory separated) and I not willing to change it to run in single process. Rather I'd like to tell my `gdb` to **automatically** track each child process created by the parent process my `gdb` runs.

What's the right way to go?

Comment: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug the child process after fork() in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199270/how-do-i-debug-the-child-process-after-fork-in-gdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to tell my gdb to automatically track each child process created by the parent process my gdb runs.

You can write a Python program to do that (assuming recent GDB built with embedded Python).

Often a much easier approach is to modify the failing test case like so (I am using gUnit example here, but the same technique [works in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41053352/50617)):

```
TEST(Foo, Bar) {
  // Start added code.
  volatile int go = 0;  // Modified from GDB.
  while (go == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Run 'gdb -p %d'\n", getpid());
    sleep(1);
  }
  // End.

  EXPECT_EQ(123, Bar());  // This is the test which fails.
}
```

Now just run all your tests, attach GDB when the test case runs, set breakpoints as desired, set `go` to 1 and `continue`.

P.S. Most test frameworks already have a mechanism to attach debugger on failure. If you are dealing with one that doesn't, you may want to fix *that*.